# Find Word in 2d char matrix

Tags: python, string, list, 2d

> Problem :
> Given a 2D grid of characters and a word `w`, find number of occurrences of given word in the input grid. A word can be matched in up, down, left and right directions.
>
> Note : Length of each row may be different.

```
Input format :
Line 1 : n (Number of rows in input grid)
Next n lines : Characters of each row in different lines
Line (n+2)nd : Given word, w
Output format :
Count of w
Constraints :
1 <= n <= 100
Input :
3
rtoe
aotl
ttot
to
Output :
8
```

I tried the approach below but got an error at line 15, in search2D if grid[row][col] != word[0]: `IndexError: string index out of range`

```
class GFG:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.R = None
        self.C = None
        self.dir = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], 
                     
                    [0, 1], [0, -1]]
                    
    
    def search2D(self, grid, row, col, word):
        

        if grid[row][col] != word[0]:
            return False

        for x, y in self.dir:
            

            rd, cd = row + x, col + y
            flag = True

            for k in range(1, len(word)):
                

                if (0 <= rd <self.R and
                    0 <= cd < self.C and
                    word[k] == grid[rd][cd]):
                    

                    rd += x
                    cd += y
                else:
                    flag = False
                    break
            

            if flag:
                return True
        return False

    def patternSearch(self, grid, word):
        global res
        self.R = len(grid)
        self.C = len(grid[0])
        res = 0
        for row in range(self.R):
            for col in range(self.C):
                if self.search2D(grid, row, col, word):
                    res+=1
                    
# Driver Code
res=0
n = int(input())
grid = []
for i in range(n):
    s = input()
    grid.append(s)
pattern = input()
gfg = GFG()
gfg.patternSearch(grid, pattern)
print(res)
```

Comment: In the spec you note that `Length of each row may be different.` But in your code it looks like you set a fixed length for R in patternSearch. My guess is that this is whats causing your issue.

Comment: @njwfish , pls help with code if possible